# Get Google+ friends from People API

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-people-api

I'm trying to get all the Google+ friends from the People API.

I'm getting all my contacts as expected only the G+ contacts missing.

I have requested following Scopes

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder( GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN )
                .requestIdToken( getString( R.string.default_web_client_id ) )
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .requestScopes( new Scope( Scopes.PLUS_ME ) )
                .requestScopes( new Scope( PeopleScopes.CONTACTS ) )
                .requestScopes( new Scope( PeopleScopes.PLUS_LOGIN ) )
                .requestScopes( new Scope( PeopleScopes.USERINFO_PROFILE ) )
                .build();
```

Did i've forgotten some Scopes? Otherwise how do I acces them? My approach is to do the following. This returns my google contacts contacts except the Google+ accounts from my friends.

```
People service = new People.Builder( HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential )
                        .setApplicationName( "REST API sample" )
                        .build();
ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = service
                    .people()
                    .connections()
                    .list( "people/me" )
                    .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Google People API doesn't have a way to get a list of Google+ friends. You can only get a list of people you have in your contacts.

Comment: Unfortunately the deprecated Google+ API list call no longer returns connected people. So there is no way to get this info.